# Move RecyclerView to top of screen then start scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have a UI screen which has textView, button and recyclerview vertically aligned.

I want to build an animation where RecylerView scrolls up on top of TextView + Button and first moves (moves not scrolls) till top of the screen then it starts scrolling.

In that situation;
TextView and Button will be hidden behind RecyclerView.
(I think this can be achieved by using Framelayout and putting textView and Button in one ViewGroup (say textButtonLayout) and putting RecyclerView below that ViewGroup (textButtonLayout).

Same way, when scrolling down, first it should scroll down (scroll not move) once scrolling is done then RecyclerView should move to its original position which is below button.

[image]

Comment: Let's say the RecyclerView is moved to top and covered other views. Is it going to fill the whole screen (from the tabs to the bottom)? In this case more items will be visible on screen. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Hamed Yes thats the plan :)

Answer (score -1):

Put your other Views and the RecyclerView in a `NestedScrollView`

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_home_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Second"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Previous" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: It will make all views move up/down together. My requirement is recyclerview should move on top of button+textView.

Comment: Finally I am able to achieve it using Motion Layout.